# How to make resource files privatly and locally accessible to the application with app.yaml in GAE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, yaml

In [appengine-web.xml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref) we have `<resource-files>` tag to make resources files accessible to the application at runtime but not public, but in the new [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/config/appref) we don't.

How can I make files privatly and locally accessible to the application with app.yaml like it used to be with the `<resource-files>` tag in Google App Engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deploying a test application, I could verify that it's not necessary any special configuration in `app.yaml` anymore to have access to the contents of WEB-INF. Everything there can be used using the `ServletContext` method `getResource` and `getResourceAsStream` as expected.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/config/appref-xml)

> If you are using an appengine-web.xml in your project, the **app.yaml is automatically generated for you at deployment**.

Why not just create the `appengine-web.xml` as you normally would. Deploy your app. Then take a look at the generated `app.yaml` file

Comment: I ended up doing this, and the reason for the question is that this try and error method takes time, you need to set up a project for test, create a minimal application and etc. I will answer my question with the result so others don't have to do this like me.